# Setting UITextView height based on contentSize inside a UITableViewCell only works after the initial table load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a **UITextView** inside a **UITableViewCell**. I am attempting to set the height of the **UITextView** it based on the content size. Inside my *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method I have:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
....
cell.text.text = textString; // cell.text is the UITextView
CGRect frame = cell.text.frame;
frame.size.height = cell.text.contentSize.height;
cell.text.frame = frame;

return cell;
```

There are other objects on the custom cell, but nothing has constraints. The interesting thing is that when the table view is first loaded, the UITextView does not resize. However, when another cell is loaded by scrolling down or back up, the UITextView resizes to the correct height based on the above code. Why isn't the initial table loading correctly.

The UITextView has a default width and height size. Let me know if I can add more details. I am not implementing *heightForRowAtIndexPath*, but the testing I am doing has not exceeded the default cell heights so this should not matter anyways.

Comment: The trouble is you need to know the height of the text view before you can find out the width of the table view cell. After many partially working attempts I ended up taking the table view width and subtracting a hard coded number of pixels depending on `[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you log the value of `cell.text.contentSize.height` ?
At that moment you don't get the correct value, I think you should set the height on the following `UITableView` callback:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: The same values are logged in both cellForRowAtIndexPath: and willDisplayCell:. I believe it has something to do with how I'm reusing cells so I am reading more into that documentation to make sure I set everything up right.

Comment: So, you got the same value for `cell.text.contentSize.height`, and if you set this value to the `UITextView.frame.size.height` it doesn't take effect?
How do you know that `UITextView.frame.size.height` doesn't change? Do you have a background color on the `UITextView`? Or are you expecting to reduce the number of text lines?

Comment: The value for `cell.text.contentSize.height` is incorrect. It is not the real height of the content. It does take effect, but it is wrong. I am using a background color for testing. When more cells are loaded through scrolling down or back up, the value for `cell.text.contentSize.height` is right and the background color confirms this.

Comment: Ok, so you need to change the calculation of the height, try this:

`CGSize textsize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width,999) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];`

Comment: It works after the initial load but not at first. So when the ViewController containing this loads, I see the wrong size area. If I scroll down and the app loads more cells, the UITextView resizes correctly. If I scroll back up and it reloads the original cells, the UITextView resizes correctly. Any idea of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `[cell.text layoutIfNeeded]` before calling `cell.text.contentSize`

The contentSize will be unknown by the UITextField until it has been drawn. Calling `layoutIfNeeded` should force the computation of layout size.

Comment: Still not working until after the initial loading of the table view.

Comment: In that case you may use `sizeWithAttributes:`of class NSString to get the size that your string will take on display.

Comment: It works after the initial table load, but not for the first cells. So when the ViewController containing this loads, I see the wrong size area. If I scroll down and the app loads more cells, the UITextView resizes correctly. If I scroll back up and it reloads the original cells, the UITextView resizes correctly. Any idea of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If finaly made it work with this, try it

```
cell.text.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textString];
float textViewWidth      = cell.text.frame.size.width;
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
cell.text.contentSize    = [cell.text sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textViewWidth, FLT_MAX)];
[cell.text sizeToFit];
```